# Best way to make current git history accessible to view for others

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging, collaboration

When I work with other people, I often like to take a look at what they've done so far or I would like to let them know what I've been doing.

Let me note that in such a state, the code may be unusable in a way that a new feature disturbs something and I am just trying to figure out how to resolve this, so the commit itself might not be “finished”.

Is there any efficient way of giving them a possibility to view my commits **without** having to create a new remote branch?

A Remote branch has severe disadvantages for this task, because

- I will very likely change significant parts of the git history with `git rebase --interactive` or do amend committing
- Others should not be able to interfere with my work
- I neither want to remove old branches (in this case I am not even permitted to do so) nor inflate the remote git history with a new temporary branch every time I want to show others my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to provide is read-only access or some other kind of access control, you probably want to look into repository browsing/management software.

*However*, if you are sharing your work with a **trusted user**, you can ask them to create new remotes. This fulfills your #1 and #3 desires of not polluting your `origin` with extra branches.

Given you are `a-host` and you want to share your `my-repo.git` with `b-host`, a user on `b-host` can do the following:

```
b@b-host$ git remote add wip git-user@a-host:/my-repo.git
b@b-host$ git remote show
origin
wip
b@b-host$ git checkout wip/master
```

Beware that user `b@b-host` can write to your local(on `a-host`) repository in this case, because you must necessarily have granted it access to some `git-user` on your machine.